# mongoose and express i want user related data in comment modal

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a user ,post,comment modal

This is my comment modal

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  postId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Post",
  },
  userId: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
  },
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  image: {
    type: String,
  },
  likes: {
    type: Array,
    default: [],
  },
});

export default mongoose.model("Comment", CommentSchema);
```

and this is my addComment controller

```
export const addComment = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId);
    if (!post) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid Post Id" });
    }
    const comment = await new Comment(req.body);
    await comment.save();
    res
      .status(200)
      .json({ success: true, message: "Comment added Successfully!" });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error!" });
  }
};and this is my getComments controller

export const getAllCommentsOfPost = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId);
    if (!post) {
      return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid Post Id" });
    }
    const comments = await Comment.find({ postId: req.body.postId });
    res.status(200).json({ success: true, comments: comments });
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error!" });
  }
};
```

This is my response

```
{
    "success": true,
    "comments": [
        {
            "_id": "65f2eec753e8de0aa1fffb26",
            "postId": "65f2e983f80127323fc86d8e",
            "content": "bad",
            "likes": [],
            "__v": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

in the response i am only getting postId , why am i not getting userId despite mentioning userId in comment modal and referenced it to user Modal and also how can i get the username as well .I need both username and userId in comments modal, can you guys tell me ways to do it?

Comment: When you do `const comment = await new Comment(req.body);` does `req.body` contain a `userId` property and value? Can you `console.log('body', req.body)` to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you're retrieving comments using Comment.find({ postId: req.body.postId }), which fetches comments based on the postId field only. To also include the userId and username fields from the referenced User model, you need to perform a population query.

Here's how you can modify your getAllCommentsOfPost function to include the userId and username fields:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import Comment from "./CommentModel"; // Import your Comment model
import User from "./UserModel"; // Import your User model

export const getAllCommentsOfPost = async (req, res) => {
 try {
  const post = await Post.findById(req.body.postId);
  if (!post) {
   return res.status(404).json({ message: "Invalid Post Id" });
  }

  // Use populate() to retrieve comments with user information
  const comments = await Comment.find({ postId: req.body.postId })
  .populate("userId", "_id username"); // Populate userId field and select _id and username

   res.status(200).json({ success: true, comments: comments });
 } catch (err) {
   res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error!" });
 }
};
```

In the populate() method, the first argument is the field you want to populate (userId in this case), and the second argument is the fields you want to select from the populated document (_id and username in this case).

With this modification, the comments array in the response will include objects with both the postId and userId fields, as well as the username field from the referenced user document.